# C#: How to generate StreamContent only for first line of file

Tags: c#

I have files with the first line as a header,

[image]

Now, I have a Web API Controller code which accepts only `StreamContent`,

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Files\test_Copy.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                await result.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
```

From client application, I am converting `fileStream` to `StreamContent` and post to Web API call.

```
Content = new StreamContent(fileStream),
```

I am able to send entire file content using the below code. Question: Can I send only the first line of the file as `StreamContent`?

Here I am using both client and server code in a console application,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Get().Wait();
    }


    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Files\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //how to send only first line of file as a "Content"
                Content = new StreamContent(fileStream),
            };

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Files\test_Copy.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                await result.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
string line1 = File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").First(); 
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( line1 );
using (var stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray ))
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the first line into a `MemoryStream` and then passing that into `StreamContent`:

```
var memStr = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(memStr);
var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

// Write first line to memStr
writer.Write(reader.ReadLine()); 

var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //how to send only first line of file as a "Content"
    Content = new StreamContent(memStr),
};
```

*Note: Please ensure you dispose of the objects*.